# Jetty Container Authentication in Grails 3

Tags: authentication, grails, jetty, grails3

I'm trying to configure the `jetty` container authentication for `FORM` method. I used to inject below configs to `web.xml` in Grails 2 but seems it's not possible in Grails 3 as it does not support web.xml anymore.

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
       <form-login-page>/logon.html?param=test</form-login-page>
       <form-error-page>/logonError.html?param=test</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
```

How can this be achieved in Grails3?

Comment: Are you deploying a runnable jar or to an external Jetty server?

Comment: @JamesKleeh I'm using embedded jetty

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a servlet container customizer

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-jetty

```
class EmbeddedCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
    @Override
    void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

    }
}
```

Then just register the class as a bean